# How to compare windows versions in a batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I'm used to script programming in Linux, but now I need to do a very simple script for windows that does something depending on the version of the operative system.

I have seen that the `ver` command returns the version, but I don't know how to compare the output of this command with a string.

In pseudo-code I only need that:

```
version = system('ver')
if version > WINDOWS_XP_VERSION then
    do_something();
end if
```

or well, by now it'd also be ok enough to do:

```
version = system('ver')
if version in [WINDOWS_VISTA_VERSION, WINDOWS_7_VERSION] then
    do_something();
end if
```

My main concern is how to compare the output of a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set Version=
for /f "skip=1" %%v in ('wmic os get version') do if not defined Version set Version=%%v
for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%Version%") do (
  set Version.Major=%%a
  set Version.Minor=%%b
  set Version.Build=%%c
)

set GTR_XP=
if %Version.Major%==5 if %Version.Minor% GTR 1 set GTR_XP=1
if %Version.Major% GTR 5 set GTR_XP=1

if defined GTR_XP (
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll finally use something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
::dirty
for /f "tokens=9 delims=Version " %v in ('ver') do set version=%v
for /f "tokens=1 delims=]" %v in ('echo %version%') do set version=%v
if %version% geq 5.1.2600 ( echo yes )
```

If you are putting above in a batch file, please add an additional `%` before `%v`. I based this on [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_%28command%29).

Comment: Thanks! It almost worked, the problem now is that the string returned by `ver` depends on the locale configuration of the operative system. Is there any way to make sure that the script is run using English locales? (i.e. is there an equivalent to LANG=C?). Or... is there any way to read the version from the register?

Comment: I don't know how to adjust locale info. Try querying the registry using `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "CurrentVersion"`.

Comment: This doesn't work for a Windows 7 ver string. I think a better delimeter to use would be "[] "